# Libgdx (Android) - ImageButton has wrong size (scale)

Tags: java, android, libgdx, scale, imagebutton

I have a problem with size of ImageButton(s), buttons are not strectched/scaled because screen size of device its 1920x1080 and button picture is 342x129. (it is viewed smaller than original picture seems).
When I draw it through this game.batch.draw(playBtn, ...);
It works fine, but I need ImageButtons. What is wrong ?
Note: WIDTH = 480, HEIGHT = 800
picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/duArh.jpg

```
public MenuScreen(PlumberGame game) {
this.game = game;
camera = new OrthographicCamera();
viewport = new FitViewport(WIDTH,HEIGHT, camera);
stage =new Stage(viewport, spriteBatch);
background = new Texture("background.png");
title = new Texture("title.png");
camera.setToOrtho(false, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
}

   @Override
   public void show() {
   stage = new Stage(); //Set up a stage for the ui
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage); //Start taking input from the ui

    atlas = new TextureAtlas("ui/buttons.pack");
    skin = new Skin(atlas);

    table = new Table(skin);
    table.setBounds(0,0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

    ImageButton.ImageButtonStyle playBtnStyle = new ImageButton.ImageButtonStyle();
    playBtnStyle.up = skin.getDrawable("playBtn");
    playBtnStyle.down = skin.getDrawable("playBtnOn");
    playBtn = new ImageButton(playBtnStyle);

    playBtn.setSize(playBtn.getWidth(), playBtn.getHeight());
    playBtn.getImage().setScaling(Scaling.fit);
    playBtn.invalidateHierarchy();
    playBtn.setPosition((float)(WIDTH * 0.15 ), (float) (HEIGHT * 0.5));
    stage.addActor(playBtn);
    }

   @Override
   public void render(float delta) {
   stage.getBatch().setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
   renderer.setProjectionMatrix(stage.getBatch().getProjectionMatrix());
    renderer.setTransformMatrix(stage.getBatch().getTransformMatrix());
    renderer.translate(WIDTH, HEIGHT, 0);
    stage.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime()); //Perform ui logic
    stage.getBatch().begin();
    stage.getBatch().draw(background, 0, 0, WIDTH,HEIGHT);
    stage.getBatch().draw(title, (float)(WIDTH * 0.12), (float) (HEIGHT * 0.75));

    stage.getBatch().end();
    stage.draw(); //Draw the ui
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
    stage.getViewport().update(width, height, true);
    table.invalidateHierarchy();
    table.setSize(width, height);
    camera.update();
    }
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Do you want the button to fill the whole screen? Or keep its ratio but fill the width? Or fill the width but not all the way to the edges?

Comment: I dont know how to explain it, but I wanna to reach this (i need to display it same way as in picture on different screen resolutions): https://imgur.com/kiSoerr

Answer (score 0):

You are setting playBtn size wrong way.

This line doesn't make sense:

```
playBtn.setSize(playBtn.getWidth(), playBtn.getHeight());
```

Comment: Yes I know I tried everything, so some lines maybe does not have a sense,I want to keep original size but with good scale (it has original size, but because of screen with higher resolution than 480x800 it has to be scaled/streched but I dont know how)

Comment: @Noro96 so why not to set it like you doing with title? `playBtn.setSize((float)(WIDTH * someValue), (float) (HEIGHT * someValue));`

Comment: because title is Texture and playBtn is ImageButton, (texture is scaled/stretched correctly) but playBtn is not (because of differnt type) so I need somehow it scale/stretch it too ...

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using Table which is really convinient when designing UIs. You specify the size of the actor when adding it to the table.

I can't try it out now since I'm not at home but it would look something like:

```
@Override
public void show() {
    stage = new Stage(); //Set up a stage for the ui
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage); //Start taking input from the ui

    atlas = new TextureAtlas("ui/buttons.pack");
    skin = new Skin(atlas);

    table = new Table(skin);
    table.setBounds(0,0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

    ImageButton.ImageButtonStyle playBtnStyle = new ImageButton.ImageButtonStyle();
    playBtnStyle.up = skin.getDrawable("playBtn");
    playBtnStyle.down = skin.getDrawable("playBtnOn");
    playBtn = new ImageButton(playBtnStyle);
    playBtn.setPosition((float)(WIDTH * 0.15 ), (float) (HEIGHT * 0.5));

    Table table = new Table();
    table.setFillParent(true);

    table.add(playBtn).expand().fillX().height(yourHeight);

    stage.addActor(table);
}
```

**EDIT:**

Another alternative is to set min size of the drawables you put in the image button style:

```
ImageButton.ImageButtonStyle playBtnStyle = new ImageButton.ImageButtonStyle();
playBtnStyle.up = skin.getDrawable("playBtn");
playBtnStyle.down = skin.getDrawable("playBtnOn");

playBtnStyle.up.setMinWidth(yourWidth);
playBtnStyle.up.setMinHeight(yourHeight);
playBtnStyle.down.setMinWidth(yourWidth);
playBtnStyle.down.setMinHeight(yourHeight);
```

Comment: not working.... it is changing size, but not scaling original size to bigger screen, I think at least I can do some mathematic formula, to count and change size for different screen resolutions, but if there is somthing similiar as setProjectionMatrix for ImageButtons I would be happy